# Automatic scaling of app

Tags: parse-platform

I was wondering whether it is possible to autoscale if the demand for requests escalates? What do people do if the app they just created goes viral in the middle of the night, and people starts getting error-codes instead of data? Or is such functionality in the pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app hits its request limit, your extra requests will begin to fail with error code 155 (RequestLimitExceeded). To prevent the requests from failing you should adjust the request limit slider for the relevant app on the on the Account Overview page.
Now, coming to your question, Can this be done automatically? As of now, I will say No. Parse currently requires you to manually do that. Having thoroughly gone through all their blog posts, I will say that there are no hints of this functionality coming in near future. Anyways this question can only be answered 100% "correctly" by someone from Parse. We, at stackOverFlow, can only guess.

Comment: But then i found this line on their forums, written by a "Parser"(as they call themselves) "We'll return an error code 155. We'll susually get in touch with customers who exceed this limit to ensure their app does not have dropped calls for an extended period of time."

Comment: But still, your problem is not solved. You say, " goes viral in the middle of the night, and people starts getting error-codes". Will Parse contact you in the middle of the night? Maybe No. Still they will ask for your permission (and payments!) for the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question you raised! As I see parse is a good PaaS with all the "cloudy" features. Even the pricing looks new generation type hourly based, however if it is lacking of automation to adjust the limits you will still pay for your unused capacity over a period of time just as in old datacenters which really bothers me (unless you pay someone to continuously monitor the performance and manually set the limits).